# Show last 2 image attachments from posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

How can i show the last 2 post attachments in my category template?

I tried the following

But i need to show the last 2 post image attachments

if i have the following code

```
function show_all_thumbs() {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);
    /* image code */
    $images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->post_parent);
    if($images){
        foreach( $images as $imageID => $imagePost ){
            unset($the_b_img);
            $the_b_img = wp_get_attachment_image($imageID, 'thumbnail', false);
            $thumblist .= '<a href="'.get_attachment_link($imageID).'">'.$the_b_img.'</a>';
        }
    }
    return $thumblist;
}
```

to display

then how can i limit the output of images displayed

Comment: I was going to downvote this question but instead I will just suggest looking here:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Hint: you have an array of results. You want to obtain last two members of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function show_all_thumbs() {
            global $post;
            $post = get_post( $post );
            /* image code */
            $images = & get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent=' . $post->post_parent );
            if( $images ) {
                $i = 0;
                $images = array_reverse( $images );
                foreach( $images as $imageID => $imagePost ) {
                    unset( $the_b_img );
                    $the_b_img = wp_get_attachment_image( $imageID, 'thumbnail', false );
                    $thumblist .= '<a href="' . get_attachment_link( $imageID ) . '">' . $the_b_img . '</a>';
                    $i++;
                    if( 2 == $i ) { break; }
                }
            }
            return $thumblist;
        }
```

Use that.  Or, use what I wrote above but take out the 
`$images = array_reverse( $images );`
line and change `&order=ASC` to `&order=DESC`